# How to create overlay video like has YouTube application in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing video app and as i see youtube app have feature of this.

I think overlay use by window view but not sure scaling uiview technique. Please guide web or text for me

help me

Comment: you want to put a play button as overlay??

Comment: I think the question is asking how to imitate the funcionality of YouTubes app, ie dragging the video playing window to the bottom corner of the screen

Comment: You should use the VideoSprite node in Sprite kit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I mean like JSA986

I think the question is asking how to imitate the funcionality of YouTubes app, ie dragging the video playing window to the bottom corner of the screen –  JSA986